# How to optimize xgb regression model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, prediction, xgboost, grid-search

I am trying to make time series predictions using XGBoost. (XGBRegressor)

I used GrindSearchCV like this:

```
parameters = {'nthread': [4],
              'objective': ['reg:linear'],
              'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.03, 0.05],
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7],
              'min_child_weight': [4],
              'silent': [1],
              'subsample': [1],
              'colsample_bytree': [0.7, 0.8],
              'n_estimators': [500]}
xgb_grid = GridSearchCV(xgb, parameters, cv=2, n_jobs=5,
                        verbose=True)
xgb_grid.fit(x_train, y_train,
             eval_set=[(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)],
             early_stopping_rounds=100,
             verbose=True)

print(xgb_grid.best_score_)
print(xgb_grid.best_params_)
```

And got those :

```
0.307153826086191
{'colsample_bytree': 0.7, 'learning_rate': 0.03, 'max_depth': 4, 'min_child_weight': 4, 'n_estimators': 500, 'nthread': 4, 'objective': 'reg:linear', 'silent': 1, 'subsample': 1}
```

I tried implementing those parameters and calculate the error. I got this:

```
MSE: 4.579726929529167
MAE: 1.6753722069363144
```

I know that an error of 1.6 is not very good for predictions. It has to be < 0.9.

I tried to micro adjust the parameters but I have not managed to reduce error more than that.

I found something about the date format, maybe that is the problem ? My data is like this : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.

I am new to machine learning and that's what I managed to do after some examples and tutorials. What should I do to lower it, or what should I search for to learn ?

I mention that I found various examples like [this one](https://jessesw.com/XG-Boost/), but I didn't understood, and of course it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried to train it with basic classifiers like `Naive Bayes` or `Linear Regressor` to see if they give you a better benchmark?

Comment: Of course the lower the error the better, but how exactly do you know that it has to be specifically < 0.9?

Comment: I have a regression problem, maybe I should have mentioned that, Naibe Bayes is for classification, and I already used Linear Regressor.  I saw many examples where the error was 0.00x